# How do I return from synchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

First, have a look at this sample:

```
var calculate = function(callback) {
  // calculating...
  callback(5);
}

var parent = function() {
  var x = 0;

  var calculatedValue = calculate(function(output) {
    return output; // return #1

    x = output;
  });

  return x; // return #2

  return calculatedValue; // return #3
}
```

My objective is to "calculate" a value within the `calculate` function, and this value must be returned by the `parent` function.

Where should I place the return statement, and what should I return with it, in order to achieve this?

I tried 3 cases:

`return #1`
Here the `output` value is returned by the `callback` function, and not the `parent` function, so parent returns undefined.

`return #2`
Here the value of x is returned before executing the `callback` function, so parent returns 0.

`return #3` + `return #1`
Here, I tried to return the `output` from the `callback`, and then (thinking that the return value of callback may somehow become the return value of the `calculate` itself), returned the `calculatedValue`, but again, parent returns undefined.

Please suggest a way, and plunk's over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdF8TzxPUPcIZDIVY94O?p=preview)

Comment: Is `calculating` asynchronous? Can you show us your actual code, please?

Comment: I hope not. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdF8TzxPUPcIZDIVY94O?p=preview). There's no actual code, it's just a thought. No worries :)

Comment: If that is really all your code, then it's synchronous (I had expected there to be something more behing `// calculating...`). So why are you using a callback at all instead of simply doing `return 5`?

Comment: @Bergi Actually, the calculate function is supposed to be some predefined library function (I mocked it up here). So, the real question here is, (synchronous or not) how to return the value of a library function, which returns values through a callback function, like calculate does?

Comment: Libraries that take callbacks are typically asynchronous, and [you cannot `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572). Use callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this *particular* case, your callback is *synchronous*, which means you can return from it like so:

```
var calculate = function(callback) {
  // calculating...
  return callback(5);
}
```

Then, you can return from the parent like so:

```
var parent = function() {    
  var calculatedValue = calculate(function(output) {
    return output; // tells the callback to do nothing with the output, just return it.
  });

  return calculatedValue; // return from parent
}
```

Note that if `calculate` is an *asynchronous* function, this approach won't work. Have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for that.

Comment: Ok, I tried this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdF8TzxPUPcIZDIVY94O?p=preview), but still got `undefined`. I hope my callback is synchronous.